# How do I add a new column and insert (calculated) data in one line?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to python so it's a basic question.

I have data that I imported from a csv file. Each row reflects a person and his data. Two attributes are Sex and Pclass. I want to add a new column (predictions) that is fully depended on those two in one line. If both attributes' values are 1 it should assign 1 to the person's predictions data field, 0 otherwise.

How do I do it in one line (let's say with Pandas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3,size=(10,2)), columns=['Sex','Pclass'])

df['prediction'] = ((df['Sex'] == 1) & (df['Pclass'] == 1)).astype(int)
print (df)
   Sex  Pclass  prediction
0    2       1           0
1    1       2           0
2    0       0           0
3    2       1           0
4    0       1           0
5    1       1           1
6    2       2           0
7    2       0           0
8    1       0           0
9    0       1           0
```

If all values are `1` and `0` only use [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143091/pyhton-how-do-i-add-a-new-column-and-insert-calculated-data-in-one-line/46143110#comment79247988_46143106) solutions:

```
#only 0, 1 values
df['predictions'] = df.all(axis=1).astype(int)

#if more possible values
df['predictions'] = df.eq(1).all(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
   Sex  Pclass  predictions
0    2       1            0
1    1       2            0
2    0       0            0
3    2       1            0
4    0       1            0
5    1       1            1
6    2       2            0
7    2       0            0
8    1       0            0
9    0       1            0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df['predictions'] = (df['Sex'] & df['Pclass']).astype(int)
```

or as proposed by @JohnGalt:

```
df['predictions'] = df.all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Demo:

```
In [68]: df['predictions'] = (df['Sex'] & df['Pclass']).astype(int)

In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   Sex  Pclass  predictions
0    1       1            1
1    1       0            0
2    0       1            0
3    0       0            0
```

Comment: `df.all(1).astype(int)` or ``df.eq(1).all(1).astype(int)`` perhaps?